# Custom Loader - onStartLoading() called when fragment returned from backstack

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager, android-loader, asynctaskloader

I have search results displayed using ViewPager & FragmentStatePageAdapter, with each set of results in its own fragment. THe data is loaded using a custom AsyncTaskLoader. I want to preserve the scroll position when going to some other activity / to background and coming back.

However, on navigation to another activity and coming back, the Loader Managers calls the onStartLoading() of the loader and unnecessarily reloads the data:

```
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (results.size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartLoading() - deliver result");
        deliverResult(mResults);
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || results.size() == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartLoading() - force load");
        // Needed for custom loaders
        forceLoad();
    }

 // Register observer...

}
```

This also means that I cannot restore the scroll position (saved on fragment's on save). Any way to avoid this reload on fragment's onResume? I am calling the initLoader() only in onActivityCreated(), which is not called when the fragment is restored from the backstack.

I am using the v4 compatibility lib.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you populating the ListView? Let's see your onLoadFinished() and onLoaderReset() calls in your fragment/activity.

Comment: onLoadFinished() calls fillAdapter after checking the search keyword hasn't changed. My onLoaderReset() just clears the adapter.

Comment: Just noticed this too... Very weird. :/ Had to prevent this with a boolean that ignored the result in onLoadFinished().

Answer (score 0):

A small hint to check ... when you `initLoader` it might not call `onStartLoading` but it will for sure call `onLoadFinished` (and deliver old results).

Maybe that is happening to you?

Also try reading this thread:
[Why is onLoadFinished called again after fragment resumed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031692/why-is-onloadfinished-called-again-after-fragment-resumed)

Comment: please wrap the function names and keywords in code block from next time when you answer